# Use of Timer function in ActionScript

Tags: actionscript, timer

Action Script

I'm having trouble with timer function.

I want to make follow program.
First:generate random numbers and put up array.
Second:
carry out function with 3 second interval  by stored array.

but When using of timer function,I can't use　argument　of function that  shoule be carry out interval 3second.

error message:
RangeError: Error #1125: The index 7 is out of range 4.
    at views::twoHomeView/onTimer()[C:\Users\Kinect\Adobe Flash Builder 4.6\yattah\src\views\twoHomeView.mxml:26]
    at flash.utils::Timer/_timerDispatch()

### at flash.utils::Timer/tick()

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[

        import flash.display.Sprite;
        import flash.events.TimerEvent;
        import flash.utils.Timer;


        private var timer:Timer;

        public function Main()
        {
            timer = new Timer(1000, 3);
            timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, onTimer);
            timer.start();
        }
        var kaisu:int =0; 
        private function onTimer(event:TimerEvent):void
        {
        for(var i:int;i<n.length;i++){
            kaisu += 1;
            display(n[kaisu]);
        }
        }


        public  var n:Vector.<int> = new Vector.<int>(4);   

        public var a:int　=0;
        public var s:int　=0;


            function display(q:int):void{//show the picture(ue,migi,shita,hidari)　0=↑1=→2＝↓３＝←
            if(q ==0)
            {
                ue.visible= true;
                migi.visible= false;
                shita.visible= false;
                hidari.visible= false;
            }
            else if(q ==1)
            {

                ue.visible= false;
                migi.visible= true;
                shita.visible= false;
                hidari.visible= false;
            }
            else if(q ==2)
            {
                ue.visible= false;
                migi.visible= false;
                shita.visible= true;
                hidari.visible= false;
            }
            else
            {
                ue.visible= false;
                migi.visible= false;
                shita.visible= false;
                hidari.visible= true;
            }
                }
        protected function button1_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            display(0);
        }

        protected function button2_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            display(0);


        }

        protected function right_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            display(1);
        }





        function wait(time:int, handler:Function):void

        {

            var timeri:Timer = new Timer(time, 1);

                timeri.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, timerHandler);

                timeri.start();

            function timerHandler(event:TimerEvent):void

            {

                    handler();

                    timeri.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, timerHandler);

            }

        }   
        function lv1():void{
    }

        function showMC():void//put random number in array
        {

            for(var i:int;i<n.length;i++)
            {   var r:int = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
                n[i]=r;
            }   
            point.text = n[0]+""+" "+n[1]+" "+n[2]+" "+n[3];
        }








    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<fx:Declarations>
</fx:Declarations>


<s:Image x="-31" y="-40" width="383" height="486" source="assets/yattah.jpg"/>
<s:Button id="left" x="13" y="304" width="50" height="50" label="←"
          click="button1_clickHandler(event)"/>
<s:Label id ="point" x="19" y="7" text="点"/>
<s:Button id="up" x="60" y="257" width="50" height="50" label="↑"
          click="button2_clickHandler(event)"/>
<s:Button id="right" x="107" y="304" width="50" height="50" label="→"
          click="right_clickHandler(event)"/>
<s:Button id="down" x="59" y="352" width="50" height="50" label="↓"
        />
<s:Button x="260" y="309" width="50" height="50" label="A" click="Main()"/>
<s:Button x="207" y="359" width="50" label="B" click="showMC()"/>
<s:Image id="ue" x="75" y="33" visible="false" smooth="true" source="assets/ue.png"/>
<s:Image id="shita" x="80" y="49" smooth="true" source="assets/shita.png"/>
<s:Image id="hidari" x="75" y="55" smooth="true" source="assets/hidari.png"/>
<s:Image id="migi" x="80" y="49" smooth="true" source="assets/migi.png"/>
<s:Image id="good" x="-21" y="84" width="363" height="103" visible="false" source="assets/good.png"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are creating a `Vector` that has 4 elements in it:

```
public  var n:Vector.<int> = new Vector.<int>(4)
```

Then in your timer event handler, you are iterating from 0 to 5 ... so you are getting the out of bounds error:

```
for(var i:int;i<5;i++) {
            kaisu += kaisu+1;
            display(n[kaisu]);
        }
```

This is further complicated by your member variable `kaisu` which you are incrementing in a funny way. I believe this is causing the error to happen before reaching the end of that for loop. You should probably make this variable a local variable (declare it in the `onTimer()` function, rather than outside of the function) ... and increment it like this:

```
kaisu += 1; // or kaisu++;
```

Finally, if you look at your `wait()` method, you are declaring a local `Timer` object. That timer can be garbage collected when the `wait()` function finishes, and it's possible that you never get any events from that timer object. To fix that, just move the declaration for `timeri` outside of the `wait()` function (make it a member variable). This is unrelated to the error but may become a problem later.